# Why when we dividing array we use condition if(start>end) return;

Tags: arrays, divide

```
void mergeSort(int *arr, int s, int e)
{

    // why do we write
    // I mean what is the significance and use of this base case.

    if (s > e)
        return;
}
```

// thats all
// its my first time asking question Stackoverflow so i apologize in advance if i //had made any mistakes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`s` means `start` (beginning index)
while `e` means `end` (ending index)

Starting index should always be `smaller` than Ending Index.

```
if (s < e) // Works Perfect
```

but if this rules violates, there would be an exception thrown. To avoid that exception, we handle it like to check it before. if it violates, no need to execute further lines/functionality.

```
if (s > e)
    return;
}
```